# Getting the parent name of a URI/URL from absolute name C#

Tags: c#, uri

Given an absolute URI/URL, I want to get a URI/URL which doesn't contain the leaf portion. For example: given http://foo.com/bar/baz.html, I should get http://foo.com/bar/.

The code which I could come up with seems a bit lengthy, so I'm wondering if there is a better way.

```
static string GetParentUriString(Uri uri)
    {            
        StringBuilder parentName = new StringBuilder();

        // Append the scheme: http, ftp etc.
        parentName.Append(uri.Scheme);            

        // Appned the '://' after the http, ftp etc.
        parentName.Append("://");

        // Append the host name www.foo.com
        parentName.Append(uri.Host);

        // Append each segment except the last one. The last one is the
        // leaf and we will ignore it.
        for (int i = 0; i < uri.Segments.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            parentName.Append(uri.Segments[i]);
        }
        return parentName.ToString();
    }
```

One would use the function something like this:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://foo.com/bar/baz.html");
        // Should return http://foo.com/bar/
        string parentName = GetParentUriString(uri);                        
    }
```

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is the shortest I can come up with:

```
static string GetParentUriString(Uri uri)
{
    return uri.AbsoluteUri.Remove(uri.AbsoluteUri.Length - uri.Segments.Last().Length);
}
```

If you want to use the Last() method, you will have to include System.Linq.

Comment: Yes, but won't this cause a problem if the URL has repeating strings: http://foo.com/bar/baz/bar

Comment: Warning: This ignores the query string.

Comment: @Brian is correct, but to clarify: Martin's solution works when a query string is present, but this is excluded from the return value.

Comment: No, it does not work well when a query string is present. Calling `GetParentUriString(new Uri("http://foo.com/bar/baz.html?q=val"))` will return `http://foo.com/bar/baz.ht`.

Comment: This doesn't behave well for paths in the form of `C:\sites\041323_KaiTakSportsPark` which is cut to `C:\sites\041323_K`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5025018/3873799) and in particular [its related comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510240/getting-the-parent-name-of-a-uri-url-from-absolute-name-c-sharp#comment14991159_5025018) is simpler and works universally

Answer (score 37):

Did you try this? Seems simple enough.

```
Uri parent = new Uri(uri, "..");
```

Comment: Slightly incorrect.  As you have it now, it is correct only if uri is a directory.  If uri is a file (as indicated in the original post) then the correct way is `Uri parent = new Uri(uri, ".");`

Answer (score 8):

There must be an easier way to do this with the built in uri methods but here is my twist on @unknown (yahoo)'s suggestion.
In this version you don't need `System.Linq` and it also handles URIs with query strings:

```
private static string GetParentUriString(Uri uri)
{
    return uri.AbsoluteUri.Remove(uri.AbsoluteUri.Length - uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length -1].Length - uri.Query.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty

```
int pos = uriString.LastIndexOf('/');
if (pos > 0) { uriString = uriString.Substring(0, pos); }
```

Comment: just an FYI...there are instances where this can break...if there is an unencoded URI in the query string which is amazingly legal

Comment: Thank you Steve. To me, it proves the point that one should never use naked string or regex manipulation for complex formats such as URI or file path :)

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way I found:

```
static Uri GetParent(Uri uri) {
    return new Uri(uri, Path.GetDirectoryName(uri.LocalPath) + "/");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PapyRef's answer is incorrect, `UriPartial.Path` includes the filename.

```
new Uri(uri, ".").ToString()
```

seems to be cleanest/simplest implementation of the function requested.

Comment: I found that it only works if the resource is a file. If it is a URL ends with `/` it won't remove the last segment.

Answer (score 1):

I read many answers here but didn't find one that I liked because they break in some cases.

So, I am using this:

```
public Uri GetParentUri(Uri uri) {
    var withoutQuery = new Uri(uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme |
                                                 UriComponents.UserInfo |
                                                 UriComponents.Host |
                                                 UriComponents.Port |
                                                 UriComponents.Path, UriFormat.UriEscaped));
    var trimmed = new Uri(withoutQuery.AbsoluteUri.TrimEnd('/'));
    var result = new Uri(trimmed, ".");
    return result;
}
```

**Note:** It removes the Query and the Fragment intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Uri(uri.AbsoluteUri + "/../")
```

Answer (score 0):

Get segmenation of url

```
url="http://localhost:9572/School/Common/Admin/Default.aspx"

Dim name() As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments

now simply using for loop or by index, get parent directory name

code = name(2).Remove(name(2).IndexOf("/"))
```

This returns me, "Common"

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd chime in; despite it being almost 10 years, with the advent of the cloud, getting the parent Uri is a fairly common (and IMO more valuable) scenario, so combining some of the answers here you would simply use (extended) Uri semantics:

```
public static Uri Parent(this Uri uri)
{
    return new Uri(uri.AbsoluteUri.Remove(uri.AbsoluteUri.Length - uri.Segments.Last().Length - uri.Query.Length).TrimEnd('/'));
}

var source = new Uri("https://foo.azure.com/bar/source/baz.html?q=1");

var parent = source.Parent();         // https://foo.azure.com/bar/source
var folder = parent.Segments.Last();  // source
```

I can't say I've tested every scenario, so caution advised.

Answer (score 0):

The most safety solution, work correctly with/without queries:

```cs
public static string GetParentUrl(string sourceUrl)
{
    return GetParentUrl(new Uri(sourceUrl));
}

public static string GetParentUrl(Uri sourceUri)
{
    return GetParentUri(sourceUri).AbsoluteUri;
}

public static Uri GetParentUri(string sourceUrl)
{
    return GetParentUri(new Uri(sourceUrl));
}

public static Uri GetParentUri(Uri sourceUri)
{
    string absolutePath = sourceUri.AbsolutePath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/');
    return new Uri($"{sourceUri.Scheme}://{sourceUri.Host}/{absolutePath}/../");
}
```